# Configure Cakephp 2.6.0 with Redis Engine

Tags: php, performance, cakephp, caching, redis

I am trying to configure cakephp ver 2.6.0 to use redis engine by default. but somehow i am not able to make it work. any help will be highly appreciated.

Things Which i have tried so far..

Configured app/config folder 2 files , core.php and bootstrap.php. , according to the guidelines provided here in this blog [configure cake with redis](http://bloke.org/php/cakephp-redis/) and this blog too [Another cake-redis config setup](http://zenofcoding.com/2013/05/07/improve-cache-and-sessions-storage-with-cakephp-and-redis/)

but i keep on getting errors like.

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'CacheException' with message 'Cache engine session is not properly configured.' in C:\wamp\www\project\cakephp\cakephp_2.6.0\lib\Cake\Cache\Cache.php on line 181

CacheException: Cache engine session is not properly configured. in C:\wamp\www\project\cakephp\cakephp_2.6.0\lib\Cake\Cache\Cache.php on line 181

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: One more thing , i am using One core multiple apps setup for my cakephp project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was having the same exact issue today while trying to setup CakePHP to use Redis as the cache engine.

Coincidentally, I also read the same setup instructions from the two blogs you linked to.

The reason was that I had copied pasted the `Configure::write(...)` code block from the [Another cake-redis config setup](http://zenofcoding.com/2013/05/07/improve-cache-and-sessions-storage-with-cakephp-and-redis/) blog post as it is and pasted it into the file without first commenting out the `Configure::write(...)` code block that was already in the core.php file.

I'm assuming that you have already successfully setup [Redis on Windows](http://redis.io) and have installed the [PHPRedis extension](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis) without any issues.

I am using the instructions from [Another cake-redis config setup](http://zenofcoding.com/2013/05/07/improve-cache-and-sessions-storage-with-cakephp-and-redis/) here.

In your app/Config/core.php file, comment out the following block: (this was starting at line 218 in my core.php)

```
    Configure::write('Session', array(
    'defaults' => 'php'
));
```

Instead, you can put this in: (You can change the values to suit your particular needs)

```
Configure::write('Session', array(
'defaults' => 'cache',
'timeout' => 100,
'start' => true,
'checkAgent' => false,
'handler' => array(
    'config' => 'session'
    )
));
```

After this, change the value of $engine to 'Redis', so it becomes:

```
$engine = 'Redis';
```

And then, put this code in, I put this in at the very end of the file: (Again, your values can be different depending on what your setup is)

```
    Cache::config ('session', array (
    'Engine' => $engine,
    'Prefix' => $prefix . 'cake_session_',
    'Duration' => $duration
));
```

And that's it. You're done! No need to change anything else.

To make sure that Redis is working properly with CakePHP, I ran the RedisEngine Test Suite that comes with CakePHP. You need to have [PHPUnit](http://www.phpunit.de) installed for this to work.

It can be accessed via http://your-cakephp-project/test.php

Click on 'Tests' under Core and then click on 'Cache/Engine/RedisEngine'
If everything is working successfully, you should see all the tests pass.

Alternatively, you can use redis-cli at the command prompt to confirm that Redis is storing keys properly.

Once you have logged in by typing redis-cli, type `KEYS *`
This should give you a list of keys related to your CakePHP setup.

An example would be the "myapp_cake_core_object_map" key.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanx for your info, My Problem was that , I didnt installed the php-redis extenstion , I was assuming that will taken care by cakephp itself, silly me. I installed that extension and everything started working smooth for me, 

but as you have mentioned the steps , this is exactly what needed to do the setup , so , I will accept it as a right answer. 

Maybe your would like to elaborate your answer by how to install phpredis and redis server. 

May be that will be helpfull to the other users of the community.

Comment: WARNING! Using this configuration will disable session locking, thus opening the door to unwanted session data overwrites!

Comment: What should be ideal $duration value of redis cache?